# jQuery Mobile ui-block not ordering right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to order with jQuery Mobile the following structure: 
[image]

I've made a JSfiddle and althought the code is equal to what I have, I dont know why it doesn't put the structure correctly. The code in JSfiddle shows the **LEFT structure**.

http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/557/

I would like to get the **RIGHT** structure. Btw, as you will see I only have one ui-grid.

```
<div class='ui-grid-a'></div>
```

Thanks.

**Edit: Solved** http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/564/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/d2FcC/)**

```
    <div class='ui-grid-a'>

    <div class='ui-block-a' style='width: 1%'></div>   
    <div class='ui-block-b' style='width: 70%;margin-bottom: 1%;'>
         <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-mini='true' data-corners='false'>
             <li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='b'>A</li>

          </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='ui-block-c' style='width: 25%; margin-left: 1%;'>
         <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-mini='true' data-corners='false'>
             <li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='b'>B</li>

          </ul>
    </div>
       <div class='ui-block-e' style=' 
margin-left: 1%;width:70%;'>
         <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-mini='true' data-corners='false'>
        <li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='b'>D</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='ui-block-d' style="width:25%;
margin-left: 1%;">
          <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-mini='true' data-corners='false'>
          <li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='b'>C</li>
              <li>HELLO</li>
              <li>HELLO</li>
              <li>HELLO</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```